# Intellij IDEA автоматический деплой измененной части проекта.

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, развертывание

Есть проект на Spring. 
При каждом изменении кода, даже самом маленьком, приходиться редеплоить весь проект. Это занимает некоторое время, что соответственно сказывается на скорости разработки.
 Есть ли какие-нибудь настройки/плагины/магия для того, чтобы IDE сама компилировала и отправляла на сервер тот или иной класс (чтобы перестать редеплоить весь проект)? 
Желательно бесплатные решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое обычно решается через деплой-сервер, который берет эту задачу на себя (и все равно компилирует все заново, и правильно делает). Конкретно в вашем случае должны помочь FileWatchers, однако придется написать консольную утилиту, которая будет скомпилированный файл отправлять на сервер.